# how to compute CPU usage with bash?

Tags: bash, cpu

I tried this:

```
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
>            sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \
>            awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'
2.1%
```

what's the meaning ?

Comment: I think it gets the CPU usage of the system idle process, then inverts it.

Comment: On my Debian, it seems to extract the idle %, then subtract that from 100, which should get all the "non-idle" fields in one number.

Comment: Refactoring the [useless use of `grep | sed | awk`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) should reduce the load, albeit only slightly.

Comment: @tripleee Dead link

Comment: @123 Sorry, should be back up later today.